# Installing Python extensions on OS X, missing MacOSX10.4u.sdk error

Tags: python, lxml, cython

I'm attempting to install various python extensions on OS X (10.6.4), with a python.org python (Python 2.6.4 (r264:75821M, Oct 27 2009, 19:48:32)). Consistently running into a problem on the gcc step. Here's a sample from compiling Cython (btw, I'm attempting to install Cython in order to install lxml):

```
In file included from /usr/include/architecture/i386/math.h:626,
                 from /usr/include/math.h:28,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/pyport.h:235,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h:58,
                 from /tmp/easy_install-Sgn5ep/Cython-0.12.1/Cython/Plex/Scanners.c:4:
/usr/include/AvailabilityMacros.h:108:14: warning: #warning Building for Intel with Mac OS X Deployment Target < 10.4 is invalid.
Compiling with an SDK that doesn't seem to exist: /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk
Please check your Xcode installation
ld: library not found for -lbundle1.o
ld: library not found for collect2: -lbundle1.o
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I get a similar error when attempting to install lxml in various ways. I've tried the winning recipe from [Simon's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277124/how-do-you-install-lxml-on-os-x-leopard-without-using-macports-or-fink), as well as the [installation instructions from the lxml site](http://codespeak.net/lxml/build.html) and they both end up with the same problem.

Do I really need to install an old OS X SDK? If so, where do I find it (a search didn't seem to turn up any official download locations).

Or is there a better workaround that doesn't require the old SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an unneccessary amount of pain, mostly brought about by my own stubbornness, this was solved by uninstalling xcode and reinstalling, this time with SDK 10.4 support checked during installation.

Comment: For others running into this on 10.6: you don't need to uninstall Xcode. Just start up a the 10.6 Xcode installer and select a custom install of the 10.4 SDK.

Comment: Thanks Ned. I tried about a million random things before I could get it to worked, so uninstalling xcode was mostly just superstition at work.