# Problems installing libxml2 on Mac OS X

Tags: python, c, macos, libxml2, scrapy

I'm trying to install libxml2 on my Mac (OS 10.6.4).  I'm actually trying to just run a Scrapy script in Python, which has required me to install Twisted, Zope, and now libxml2.  I've downloaded the latest version (2.7.7, from xmlsoft.org) and tried following these instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277124/how-do-you-install-lxml-on-os-x-leopard-without-using-macports-or-fink).  To summarize, I tried this command (in the python subdirectory):

```
python setup.py --static-deps --libxml2-version=2.7.7 -- libxslt-version=1.1.24
```

I end up with this error:

```
failed to find headers for libxml2: update includes_dir
```

Any ideas?

I also tried running this command:

```
./configure --with-python=/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/
```

And I get the following error:

```
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
```

Does that shed any light on the situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to get libxml2 installed.  It took two steps.  First, I didn't have XCode installed, so I had to get that downloaded and installed from Apple Developer Tools.  I thought that it had come standard on OX 10.6.4, but I guess not.

Then, in the libxml2 folder I ran these three commands:

```
./configure --with-python=/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.3/
make
sudo make install
```

After that, I switched to the Python subdirectory of the libxml2 folder, and ran a generic setup:

```
python setup.py install
```

After that, everything was ready to go.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread, but I just encountered this error while installing dependency with pip.

```
failed to find headers for libxml2: update includes_dir
```

I fixed it by reinstall xcode command line tools with

```
xcode-select --install
```

Hope this will help other ones who find this thread.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you write `--libxml2-version=2.7.7` instead?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the heads up.  I actually did use the correct version in the command.  On this page I had just pasted the directions from the linked page.

Comment: Careful, there's also a space between -- and libxslt-version=1.1.24

Comment: Fixed that too and still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a virtualenv and solved it adding the path to libxml2 what homebrew just installed in the global site-packages:

```
echo '/usr/local/opt/libxml2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/'  > /Users/panchicore/.virtualenvs/<virtualenv-name>/lib/python2.7/site-packages/homebrew.pth
```