# Errors in installing XMLSec on Mac OS 10.6.8

Tags: ios, xml, macos, security, libxml2

I would like to use XMLSec Library in one of my iOS app. I have followed all the instructions mentioned on http://www.aleksey.com/xmlsec/download.html and downloaded all the required libraries and frameworks. I am trying to install this library on my Mac OS 10.6.8; I have followed all the instructions mentioned on [How do you install lxml on OS X Leopard without using MacPorts or Fink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277124/how-do-you-install-lxml-on-os-x-leopard-without-using-macports-or-fink) but noting seems to work. I am facing an error while installation which is

> configure: error: You need at least libxml2 2.7.4 for this version of xmlsec1

I have tried to update the libxml2 version and followed instructions mentioned on [Problems installing libxml2 on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506327/problems-installing-libxml2-on-mac-os-x) and was successfully able to update the libxml2 version but still facing the issue "error: You need at least libxml2 2.7.4 for this version of xmlsec1" while installing the XMLSec library on Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
sudo ./configure --with-libxml=/usr/local --without-libxslt
```

You need to set `--without-libxslt` or you have to build the new version of libxslt by yourself.

Comment: Is there anyone successfully installed xmlsec on Mac OS X?