# Command 'llvm-gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, gcc, osx-lion, pip, llvm-gcc

I'm installing a package through pip and it's failing due to the following error:

```
Running setup.py install for pylibmc
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    running build_ext
    building '_pylibmc' extension
    llvm-gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -DUSE_ZLIB -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _pylibmcmodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-intel-2.7/_pylibmcmodule.o -fno-strict-aliasing
    In file included from _pylibmcmodule.c:34:

...

error: command 'llvm-gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
```

Other related questions ([What is the best way to setup Django on os X 10.7 Lion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403453/what-is-the-best-way-to-setup-django-on-os-x-10-7-lion?rq=1), [gcc-4.2 failed with exit status 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473066/gcc-4-2-failed-with-exit-status-1?rq=1), and [Why am I getting the error: command 'llvm-gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398142/why-am-i-getting-the-error-command-llvm-gcc-4-2-failed-with-exit-status-1)) all say I should install the latest Xcode and the Command Line Tools, so I did that, but the problem persists.

Are there any other solutions? I don't want to use https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer because I frequently use Xcode for other projects.

Comment: Can you give more context? Which package are you trying to install, and is there any more output? Perhaps the `--verbose` option to `pip` can help? Also, verify that you can indeed run `llvm-gcc-4.2` on the command line (even with no input files).

Comment: Added more context. It's only for the pylibmc package, and yes I can run `llvm-gcc-4.2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to `brew install libmemcached` before it would let me install pylibmc.