# ImportError: No module named lxml - Even though LXML Is installed

Tags: python, lxml, amazon-product-api

I'm getting this error "`ImportError: No module named lxml`" Even though LXML Is definitely installed. Specifically it's installed within the python Virtualenv for the project. and ultimately I'm working on the [Python/Amazon Product API](http://python-amazon-product-api.readthedocs.org/en/latest/basic-usage.html). I get the error after trying to run one of the example scripts for that project from the terminal (mac).

**How can I fix this? or further track down the issue?**

Google searching lead me to:

- Reintsall LXML
- Ensure Xcode license was agreed to: `sudo xcodebuild -license`
- Updating LXML with: `pip install --upgrade lxml` Currently at ver 3.4.0
- reinstalled LXML dependencies as outlined [here](http://lxml.de/installation.html) - `pip install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev python-dev`

The line of code throwing the error is `from lxml import etree, objectify`, this is in a folder far away from where LXML is installed in my virtual environment (although I am running the script from within my virtualenv in terminal). If the issues is simply a matter of the script not knowing where to find the LXML install, how would I fix that?

Comment: What happens when you run python from a command prompt and try `import lxml`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out that I found my answer here: [import lxml fails on OSX after (seemingly) successful install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854969/import-lxml-fails-on-osx-after-seemingly-successful-install)

Apparently, LXML Install on a Mac ends up installing it in the wrong path, so you have to reset the path using: `export PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"`

Comment: You are allowed (in fact are encouraged) to accept your own answers. There is even a badge for doing so.

Comment: Hello, I got the same error but after edit bash_profile and Path I still got the same error. It is not fix. Could you tell more detail how to put that line to which place please ?

Comment: I think I got the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729116/adding-a-module-specifically-pymorph-to-spyder-python-ide

Answer (score 3):

So it turns out that if you're using python via homebrew, things get a little sketchy with apps like Inkscape that have it hardcoded in their mind that a certain version of python is needed.

Getting the right python version was simply uninstalling brew & installing PIP:

`brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies python`

`sudo easy_install pip`

`STATIC_DEPS=true sudo pip install lxml`

Answer (score 3):

if your python is python 3.6, try `pip3.6 install lxml`