# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lxml'

Tags: python, macos, pip, lxml

I have a DevOps script that upgrade the build / version numbers in my project. It uses lxml library to parse xml type files. It was working great but all of a sudden, I got the error : `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lxml'`. I already tried updating lxml, and uninstall / reinstall but none of those worked. I also tried it with python 2.7 but got the exact same error.

I am using python3 and pip3 with aliases as following :

```
❯ which python
python: aliased to /usr/local/bin/python3
❯ which pip
pip: aliased to /usr/local/bin/pip3
```

macos Catalina `10.15.6 (19G2021)`

lxml version : `4.5.2`

python `3.8.5`

pip `20.2.3`

Comment: Do you still have the import statment?

Comment: Yes there it is : `from lxml import etree`

Comment: What was the last thing you did before you got the error, did you change something?

Comment: No that's why it's weird, I used it in the exact same version as it is now.

Comment: Was this the first time you used it today, or were you coding and it just happened in the middle?

Comment: Yes it was the first time for today. I wanted to use the script to fully finish my feature but I guess it will wait for now....

Comment: Which text editor or IDE are you using?

Comment: Check this out, it shows you how to reset the path, it is sometimes messed up.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27008222/importerror-no-module-named-lxml-even-though-lxml-is-installed

Comment: Is your question answered?

Comment: If you run a `pip3 uninstall lxml` it will show you where it's installed and ask for confirmation. Is it installed in the right place? Meaning a path included in the result of `python3 -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I managed to understand what is going on thanks to @Georges Martin. The issue was that pip was installing into `/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages` but my python3 was actually pointing to `/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/bin/python3.8` and not python3.9.