# Removed MacPorts, now Python is broken

Tags: python

I have removed MacPorts from my Mac (10.7.5) and now Python seems to be broken. I am trying to run scrapy and I get the following error at the end:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/lxml-2.3.4-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg/lxml/etree.so, 2): Symbol not found: _exsltDateXpathCtxtRegister
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/lxml-2.3.4-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg/lxml/etree.so
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libexslt.0.dylib
 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/lxml-2.3.4-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg/lxml/etree.so
```

When I run python and try to import that library, I get the same error as following:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.2 (v2.7.2:8527427914a2, Jun 11 2011, 14:13:39) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from lxml import etree
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/lxml-2.3.4-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg/lxml/etree.so, 2): Symbol not found: _xsltDocDefaultLoader
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/lxml-2.3.4-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg/lxml/etree.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/lxml-2.3.4-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg/lxml/etree.so
```

How can I clean up this mess now?

Comment: By reinstalling XSLT libraries? Your MacPorts installation supplied those, now `lxml` (an add-on library) is b0rken.

Comment: See [How do you install lxml on OS X Leopard without using MacPorts or Fink?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1277124)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: That's really out-of-date advice for someone with Lion. I believe Lion already comes with usable `libxml2` and `libxslt2` (although I _may_ be wrong—then again, even if I am, I doubt you'd want to explicitly require version 2.7.3 today…)

Comment: Please confirm the following: 1. This is the Apple-supplied Python (`/usr/bin/python`)? 2. You have no non-Apple-supplied Python installations. 3. There's something at `/usr/lib/libxml2.dylib`. 4. If you run `xml2-config --version` it reports something 2.7.0 or later. Then: How did you install `lxml`? (`pip`, `easy_install`, download the tarball/extract/`python setup.py install`, or some other way)?

Comment: I have the same problem right after installation of `lxml`. But given that I struggled to install `gcc` on OS X 10.6.8 without Xcode and then struggled to make `lxml` compile, I am not surprised that it is still not working...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming this is the system Python, and you installed `lxml` into it via `pip`, and the version of libxml2 that comes with 10.7.5 is good enough for you (I think they started shipping somewhat recent versions in 10.7—as in 2.7.x—but I can't remember for sure), it should be as simple as:

```
sudo pip uninstall lxml
sudo pip install lxml
```

The problem here is that `lxml` was built against MacPorts `libxml2`/`libxslt2`, instead of against your system versions. Theoretically it might be possible to just repoint the dependencies with `install_name_tool`, but that's more likely to fail miserably—or, if you're really unlucky, to seem to work but then crash when you really need it… Just re-building `lxml` should fix the problem. And if you used `pip`, that's as easy as uninstall/reinstall.

If you didn't use `pip`, re-doing the manual `sudo python setup.py install` from a clean copy of the tarball, or re-doing the `sudo easy_install lxml`, or doing a `sudo pip install lxml` over top of what you already have, will *probably* work, but that isn't guaranteed.

If I'm wrong about Lion coming with decent `libxml2`, please say so in a comment, and I'll give you the options for getting it (without reinstalling MacPorts).

If you want to be really sure you've cleaned everything, you can always restore your system site-packages to their default state just by doing this:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/*
rm -rf ~/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/*
```

Then, of course, you'll have to reinstall anything you installed. (If you didn't use `pip` last time, start with `sudo easy_install pip` and then use `pip` for everything else…) You can get a pretty good idea of exactly what you have installed just by doing an `ls` on those same directories, but that won't necessarily tell you *how* you installed everything. (For example, I've got a couple packages I installed with `pip install git+https://some.site/some/repo`, or from a binary installer, or in one case I have absolutely no idea…) So, consider this the nuclear option if you've got no other choice—not a first resort, but better than the thermonuclear option of reinstalling OS X.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Cleaned everything up and now it's working again.