# Installing lxml on Mac OS X 10.6.8 with gcc 4.2

Tags: c++, python, macos, gcc, lxml

I've installed gcc on Mac OS X 10.6.8 using the [osx-gcc-installer](https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer). Downloading XCode would take forever, but I managed to download and install this 170-Mb package, and I am able to compile a `Hello, world!` program using `iostream` and `std::cout`.

Then I tried to install `lxml` using python's `easy_install lxml`. It couldn't find `gcc-4.0`. I added a symbolic link of `gcc-4.0` pointing to `gcc-4.2`. Then this is what I get, any help appreciated:

```
(web)Mac-Owners-MacBook-Pro-2:python root# ./web/bin/easy_install lxml
Searching for lxml
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/lxml/
Best match: lxml 3.2.3
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/l/lxml/lxml-3.2.3.tar.gz#md5=fef47bb4ac72ac38ce778518dac42236
Processing lxml-3.2.3.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-5g5OTc/lxml-3.2.3/setup.cfg
Running lxml-3.2.3/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-5g5OTc/lxml-3.2.3/egg-dist-tmp-Rqqb9w
Building lxml version 3.2.3.
Building without Cython.
Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.28
Building against libxml2/libxslt in the following directory: /opt/local/lib
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/dist.py:266: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
  warnings.warn(msg)
warning: no files found matching '*.txt' under directory 'src/lxml/tests'
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_4lxml_5etree_4XSLT_18__call__’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:140541: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_12_XSLTContext__copy’ from incompatible pointer type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree__copyXSLT’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:141947: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_12_XSLTContext__copy’ from incompatible pointer type
/usr/libexec/gcc/powerpc-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/as: assembler (/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/ppc/as or /usr/bin/../local/libexec/gcc/darwin/ppc/as) for architecture ppc not installed
Installed assemblers are:
/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/x86_64/as for architecture x86_64
/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/i386/as for architecture i386
In file included from /usr/include/architecture/i386/math.h:626,
                 from /usr/include/math.h:28,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/pyport.h:235,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h:58,
                 from src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:16:
/usr/include/AvailabilityMacros.h:108:14: warning: #warning Building for Intel with Mac OS X Deployment Target < 10.4 is invalid.
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_4lxml_5etree_4XSLT_18__call__’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:140541: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_12_XSLTContext__copy’ from incompatible pointer type
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree__copyXSLT’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:141947: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_12_XSLTContext__copy’ from incompatible pointer type
lipo: can't open input file: /var/tmp//ccXL5TAi.out (No such file or directory)
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc-4.0' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try solution proposed [here](http://ashearer.com/blog/2011/xcode/):

```
sudo ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64" pip install lxml
```

Comment: Thanks. It helped 50%; I am still marking as accepted. It did install `lxml`, but not `lxml.etree`. I wrote some comments [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19613627/1243926).